# Parsing responseXML with Prototype's $()

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, xml-parsing, prototypejs

I've got XML coming back from an `Ajax.Request` in `Ajax.Response.responseXML`. My XML actually contains XHTML tags which I hope to append into my document.

I'm having issues appending nodes from the `responseXML` into the current document, however. I suspect that this is because they are XML nodes and not DOM nodes.

Wrapping the `responseXML` in `$()` doesn't seem to return an extended version of the nodes, either, and the documentation doesn't say that it will or won't.

Does Prototype provide a way to make use of the `responseXML`, and if not, is there a cross-browser way to parse the response and use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No prototype does not have a native way to parse XML. Nor can you extend the xml with $(xml) and then walk the DOM with .next(),.select(), etc.

Here is an example of what I did recently on a project to manually parse some XML from spell check results. Should get you started.

```
parseResults: function(results) {
var c = results.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('c');
var corrections = $A(c);
if(!corrections.size()){
  this.link.insert({ after: '<span class="spellCheckNoErrors">No spelling errors</span>' });
  (function(){ this.link.next().remove(); }.bind(this)).delay(1);
  return null;
}
this.res = $A();
corrections.each(function(node){
  sugg = node.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  offset = node.attributes[0].nodeValue;
  len = node.attributes[1].nodeValue;
        this.res.push(
    $H({
      word: this.text.substr(offset, len),
      suggestions: sugg.split(/\s/)
          })
  );
},this);
this.overlay();
},
```

Answer (score 2):

Although I accepted Christian's answer as the "correct" answer, a colleage of mine showed me *a way* to parse an XML response with Prototype.

Rather that using `responseXML`, you simply create an `Element` and then `update()` it with the `responseText`. You can then use `select()` and methods like it to traverse the nodes.